# Is there a way to put the tables in sql view for Access 2007?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I know you can put queries in SQL view but I'm trying to get the tables in SQL view so I can see the create table statement.

Comment: You mean something like `show create table yourTable`?

Comment: Like for the queries, you can see all the select statements in sql view. I want to be able to see the sql statements for the tables also

Comment: the `create` statement? the `insert` statements for each row? what do you want to show?

Comment: Both if possible for each of the tables in access

Comment: You can use VBA to write both: there's no built-in functionallity for doing this (sounds to me that you want to create a "dump file" of the database)

Comment: check this: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=45447#p210299

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no built-in way to show a `create table` expression in Access.

You can, however, create your own VBA function that does precisely that:

```vb
public function showCreateTable(tblName as String) as String
    dim db as DAO.Database, tbl as DAO.TableDef, fld as DAO.field
    dim field
    dim strSQL as string
    dim i as integer
    set db = currentdb()

    for each tbl in db.tableDefs
        if tbl.Name = tblName then
            strSQL = "create table " & tblName & "("
            i = 1
            for each fld in tbl.fields
                if i > 1 then
                    strSQL = strSQL & ", " & vbCrLf
                else
                    strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf
                end if
                strSQL = strSQL & fld.Name & " "
                select case fld.Type
                    case dbBigInt: strSQL & "bigint"
                    case dbBinary: strSQL = strSQL & "binary"
                    case dbBoolean: strSQL & "boolean"
                    case dbChar: strSQL = strSQL & "char("& fld.size & ")"
                    ' You go on with every type listed in the Field.Type possible values
                end select
                i = i+1
            next fld
            strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & ")"
            exit for
        end if
    next tbl
    showCreateTable = strSQL
end function
```

The `Field.Type` possible values are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845405.aspx).